# Remove duplicates from array directive

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a div which shoes the names. I want to remove the duplicates in my array. I have done this with `filter`, but i want to know how we can extend this to build a `directive`.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in names | unique">
                {{name}}
            </li>   
        </ul>
</div>
```

Below is the filter code.

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.names = ['a','b','c','d','a','c'];
    }])
    .filter('unique', function(){
        return function(names){
            var obj = {};
            names.forEach(function(name){
                obj[name] = null;
            })
            return Object.keys(obj);
        }
    })
    .directive('unique', function(){
        return {
            link: function(scope, elem, attr){

            }
        }
    })
```

How can i build a `directive` which removes duplicates from my array.

Comment: Why do you need a directive?

Comment: @PSL: I am interested to know how you could do the same with directive. What would the directive return etc....

Comment: It does not make sense actually to do it in a directive to transform the data that is exactly what filters are for... Or are you looking for something more than just transforming the data?

Comment: @PSL: I am just looking to remove the duplicates alone, i know filters are for that purpose.. just interested... to know.

Comment: To compare objects, arrays, etc, angular have the `angular.equals(o1, o2);` function. And to delete, use `delete names[names.indexOf(name)];`.

Comment: You can just simplify your filter to: `return names.filter(function(name, idx, list) {
      return list.indexOf(name) === idx;
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would write it:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.names = ['a','b','c','d','a','c'];
    }])
    .directive('uniqueArray', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                arr: '='
            }
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in unique_arr">{{item}}</li></ul>',
            controller: function($scope){

                function get_unique(items){
                    var obj = {};
                    angular.forEach(items, function(item){
                        obj[item] = null;
                    });
                    return Object.keys(obj);
                }

                $scope.unique_arr = get_unique($scope.arr);
            }
        }
    })
```

and in the HTML:

```
<unique-array arr="names"></unique-array>
```

I think a directive is unnecessary as though as it's basically acting as a wrapper

Comment: Can you help me in this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035944/can-anyone-explain-me-this-password-match-directive