# Can anyone explain me this password match directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can anyone explain me on how this piece of code works.

**HTML Markup**

```
<input type="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
<input type="password" ng-model="confirm_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required validate-equals="password">
```

**Directive Code**

'use strict';

```
angular.module('raJwtApp')
  .directive('validateEquals', function () {
    return {
      require: "ngModel",   
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        function validate(value){
          console.log(value, scope.$eval(attrs.validateEquals));
            var valid = (value === scope.$eval(attrs.validateEquals));
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('equal', valid);
            return valid ? value : undefined;
        }

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(validate);
        ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(validate);

        scope.$watch(attrs.validateEquals, function(){
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
        })
      }
    };
  });
```

Can anyone explain me the below `questions`.

What does the below code do in the `directive`?. **I don't really understand on how this password match directive works?.**

```
$scope.watch(attrs.validateEquals, function(){  
    //ngModelCtrl.$viewValue always returns undefined      
    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't have a $setDirty (although it does have a $setPristine), so the way to set a model as dirty is via its control:

```
ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
```

In your directive, therefore, the $watch is checking for a change to the validateEquals attribute (password), and then sets the model to dirty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="password_form">
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" ng-model="confirm_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required validate-equals="password">
</form>
<button ng-disabled="password_form.$invalid">save</button>
```

in `<form>`, you can do angular validation by checking a form's flags such as `$invalid` or `$error` (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms (Custom Validation))

This is useful for simple validation such as:

- a required field (adding `required` to `<input>`) or
- a minimum # of characters (adding `min='5'`)

and `password_form.$invalid` will automatically be set if either requirements fail.

The `validate-equals` is a directive to set the form's `$invalid` (or `$dirty`?) flag manually if the two password fields don't match.

`$setViewValue` is called to re-evaluated the form's validity.

> The validation functions are executed every time an input is changed ($setViewValue is called) or whenever the bound model changes.